# Reputation is not shown correctly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, linked-accounts

I have ***602*** reputation in my [Stack Overflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1141537/imran-rana):

---

[image]

---

But it is shown ***587*** in **Accounts** section of other linked sites [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/184542/imran-rana) like:

---

[image]

---

What is going on, someone explain please.

**BTW:** I used reputation recalc a few days ago.

Comment: Caching. It's always caching. Wait 24 hours. If it's still wrong *then* report it as a bug, however, you'll have received more reputation in the meantime so it will still be out of sync :)

Comment: Also, rep recalc isn't needed any more; the "Trigger Reputation Recalc" button is kept for nostalgia purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ChrisF has said in the comments, this is network-level caching.  Your profile should have fixed itself now.